# Form question - freeform /mailchimp

Tags: plugin-freeform

Looking at this plugin.
https://solspace.com/craft/freeform

Need a form to do this, any help would be pic guys.

Fill in form - sends email to nominated email with enquiry

If sign up to newsletter is chosen then the name is added to mailchimp list and opt in email sent

If sign up response is negative form still sends email to us, but the users email is not added to the mailchimp list or is added with a status of unsubscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freeform includes [mail list integration](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/mailing-list-integrations/) for MailChimp, Constant Contact (pro only) and Campaign Monitor (pro only).

[As per their documentation](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/mailing-list-integrations/), form fields can be mapped to your mail list. You can include a checkbox so visitors can choose to subscribe when submitting a form. If they do tick the checkbox, they will be sent a double opt in email (if this is enabled).

Do bear in mind though that MailChimp is [rolling out single opt-in](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/about-double-opt-in) from 31st October 2017 unless you're within the EU.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Sam

Comment: No worries buddy! Remember to accept my answer if you're happy with it :)

Comment: Thanks Sam, was really helpful. I don't suppose you have any further light on how to implement the conditional mailchimp subscribe do you? Just bit stuck on that bit.

Comment: Ah think I have it 'Mailing list integrations' seems to have a checkbox option I can use on composer, once API is set, bingo. Thanks Sam

Comment: Glad you found it.